Pie chart labels are overlapping on the mobile screen
I created a pie chart using the JS code below. The chart works fine on desktop, but the labels overlap on mobile screens. I've tried adjusting the width and height for mobile and explored several solutions, but I haven't found a proper fix. Could someone please help me resolve this issue?
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>
<script>
var pluginLabelsExtension = {
    afterDatasetsUpdate(chart){
        if(chart._labels && chart._labels.length > 0){
            this._installLabelPatch(chart._labels[0].constructor);
        }
    },

    _installLabelPatch(Label){
        if(Label.prototype._patched){
            return;
        }
        Label.prototype._patched = true;
        const _getFontColor = Label.prototype.getFontColor,
            _renderArcLabel = Label.prototype.renderArcLabel;

        // use getFontColor to also get the `reverse` option for this element; save in element._view
        Label.prototype.getFontColor = function(dataset, element, index){
            var fontColor = _getFontColor.call(this, dataset, element, index);
            var reverse = false,
                optionReverse = this.options.reverse;
            if(typeof optionReverse === typeof true){
                reverse = optionReverse;
            }
            else if(typeof optionReverse === 'function'){
                reverse = optionReverse({
                    label: this.chart.config.data.labels[index],
                    value: dataset.data[index],
                    percentage: this.getPercentage(dataset, element, index),
                    backgroundColor: dataset.backgroundColor[index],
                    dataset: dataset,
                    index: index
                });
            }
            else if(Array.isArray(optionReverse)){
                reverse = optionReverse[index];
            }
            element._view.reverse = reverse;
            return fontColor;
        }

        Label.prototype.renderArcLabel = function(label, renderInfo){
            if(renderInfo.view.reverse && typeof label === 'string'){
                var ctx = this.ctx, radius = renderInfo.radius, view = renderInfo.view;
                var deltaToCenterFromEnd = renderInfo.startAngle - view.startAngle - Math.PI / 2;
                ctx.save();
                ctx.translate(view.x, view.y);
                ctx.rotate(renderInfo.endAngle - deltaToCenterFromEnd);
                ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                ctx.textAlign = 'left';
                var lines = label.split('\n'), max = 0, widths = [], offset = 0;
                if(this.options.position === 'border'){
                    offset = (lines.length - 1) * this.options.fontSize / 2;
                }
                for(var j = 0; j < lines.length; ++j){
                    var mertrics = ctx.measureText(lines[j]);
                    if(mertrics.width > max){
                        max = mertrics.width;
                    }
                    widths.push(mertrics.width);
                }
                for(var j = 0; j < lines.length; ++j){
                    var line = lines[j];
                    var y = (lines.length - 1 - j) * -this.options.fontSize + offset;
                    ctx.save();
                    var padding = (max - widths[j]) / 2;
                    ctx.rotate(padding / radius);////
                    for(var i = 0; i < line.length; i++){
                        var char = line.charAt(i);
                        mertrics = ctx.measureText(char);
                        ctx.save();
                        ctx.translate(0, -1 * radius);
                        ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
                        ctx.fillText(char, 0, y);
                        ctx.restore();
                        ctx.rotate(-mertrics.width / radius);
                    }
                    ctx.restore();
                }
                ctx.restore();
            }
            else{
                _renderArcLabel.call(this, label, renderInfo)
            }
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var data = {
            datasets: [{
                data: [125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125],
                backgroundColor: ["#FE4D42","#FFD405","#58E152","#00D59F","#8B7DFF","#E85FED","#F71663","#4F94FF"]
            }],
            labels: [
                "Arts and Creativity",
                "Careers and Employment",
                "Communities and Social",
                "Culture and Heritage",
                "Learning and Skills",
                "Personal Finance",
                "Self-Environment",
                "Wellbeing"
            ]//.map(s => s.split(/[ \-]/)[0])
        };

        var labels_url = {
            "Arts and Creativity" : "arts-and-creativity",
            "Careers and Employment" : "careers-and-employment",
            "Communities and Social" : "communities-and-social",
            "Culture and Heritage" : "culture-and-heritage",
            "Wellbeing" : "health",
            "Learning and Skills" : "learning-and-skills",
            "Personal Finance" : "personal-finance",
            "Self-Environment" : "self-environment"
        };

        var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx,{
            type: 'pie',
            data: data,
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                //animation: false,
                plugins: {
                    labels: {
                        render: 'label',
                        arc: true,
                        fontColor:["#FF7805","#0854A3","#14A400","#048A7D","#502788","#F200F2","#FF0068","#000962"],
                        reverse: [false, false, true, true, true, true, false, false],
                        fontSize: 18,
                        position: 'outside'
                    }
                }
            },
            plugins:[
                pluginLabelsExtension
            ]
        });

        canvas.onclick = function(evt) {
            var activePoints = myNewChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
            if (activePoints[0]) {
                var chartData = activePoints[0]['_chart'].config.data;
                var idx = activePoints[0]['_index'];

                var label = chartData.labels[idx];
                var value = chartData.datasets[0].data[idx];

                var url = "https://www.maximiseme.co.uk/" + labels_url[label];
                //alert(url);
                console.log(url);
                window.location.href = url;
            }
        };
    }
);
</script>

I want the pie chart labels to be readable on mobile screens without overlapping.

If your pie chart has more than 2 slices, you're using the wrong chart type. If the labels are so close together that they overlap, you're using the wrong visualisation for your data. Instead of a pie chart, use a horizontal bar chart, sorted by value. Then all the values can be properly compared, and all the labels will be visible. If you want to learn more about why pie charts are not the best in all situations, check out this article from the data viz pope Stephen Few: https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf
